# Set ether amount for variable on constructor

Tags: solidity

So I know I can set a `uint amount = 0.4 ether` , but what if I want to declare it elsewhere? like declare `uint amount` and then in the constructor set it

```
constructor(uint _amount){
amount = _amount ether
}
```

but clearly I can't initialize it like that,
so how would it be done? in wei? is there a way to convert eth to wei and set it there? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [ether unit](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units) is only available with numeric literals (in the current Solidity version 0.8).

But since it effectively represents multiplication by 10^18, you can perform the multiplication on the variable.

```
// multiply `_amount` by "10 to the power of 18"
amount = _amount * 1e18;

// same thing, just different syntax
amount = _amount * (10 ** 18);
```

*Note that the arithmetic operation usually described by caret `^` is described by two asterisks `**` in Solidity.*